# Search text hides search icon in text input html

Tags: html, css

I have a text input with search icon in it. If the characters in text box exceed its length, the search icon gets hidden. How can I make it not to hide.

See this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEPSQ.png)

Below is the code-

```
         <div class="mainClass">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search names"/>
                <img src="Content/Search.png" class="imageClass"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <style>
        .mainClass{
            float:right;
        }
        .imageClass{
            width:10px;
            height:10px;
            margin-left:-10%;
        }
    </style>
```

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add padding-right to your input
This will provide space for your icon

```
input {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```css
.mainClass {
  float: right;
}

.imageClass {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: -10%;
}

input {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainClass">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search names" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" class="imageClass" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way other than using padding-right?

Answer (score 0):

Just make them both `display:inline-block;`

```css
.mainClass {
    float: right;
    border:1px solid;
    padding:0 5px;
}

.mainClass>input[type=text] {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.imageClass {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainClass">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search names"/>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" class="imageClass"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ZohirSalak.!